# Graphics.TextRenderingHint property doesn't change in printing

Tags: c#, printing, gdi+

I have an application whose job is to print over preexisting preprinted labels, so it is really important that the text is printed in a precise way, exactly as it looks like when the user places it during editing.
I use GDI+ methods to do that.

I noticed that there is a difference between the printed font and the one shown in the preview and I found out that during printing it is not possible to set the Graphics.TextRenderingHint property to any value than SingleBitPerPixelGridFit. I try to set the value of TextRenderingHint to AntiAlias, but it doesn't change.

Here is an example of the code:

```
  private void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument printDoc = (PrintDocument)sender;
        e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
        //I try to set the value of TextRenderingHint to AntiAlias, but it doesn't change
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

        string line = "Line of text";
        System.Drawing.Font textFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 5f, FontStyle.Regular);
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(line, textFont, Brushes.Black, position.X, position.Y, sf);
    }
```

I think that I should use an option of the TextRenderingHint independent from the grid fitting in order to have the printed document absolutely identical to the preview.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: _I try to set the value of TextRenderingHint to AntiAlias, but it doesn't change._ What do you mean? The setting doesn't stick? Or the result doesn't change?

Comment: I mean that even if I set it with this line of code: `e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;` the value of e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint is always SingleBitPerPixelGridFit. So the setting doesn't stick.

Comment: [Looks like this is right](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99e41f11-7b02-4f5a-bcf5-dd9033ac4bb7/textrenderinghint-cant-be-changed-when-printing?forum=csharplanguage) and won't go away. You just can't anti-alias printed pixels the way you can pixels on screen

Comment: There is one way to get identical output, and that is to create a high resolution bitmap, and print that. But if you render to the printer, the GDI+ calls are converted to printer commands that use high resolution fonts on the printer, which normally does not use the primitive anti-aliasing we need on monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was trying to get ClearTypeGridFit displayed, but only SingleBitPerPixelGridFit was displayed. I found out that I did not enable ClearType in the display settings. After enabling ClearType the TextRenderingHint started to work. Just something to check.